# Outlook - Show Custom Ribbon when a mail is selected

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin, ribbon-control, winforms-interop

I have a custom ribbon which I have to show when a mail selected and also when the mail is opened by double click. I have the button placed correctly when a mail is opened  by double click.

How to get the ribbon when a mail is selected? [Mail body is shown in the reading pane].

Answer (score 0):

First, add an event handler in the startup method:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.ActiveExplorer().SelectionChange += activeExplorer_SelectionChange;
}
```

Then, in the event handler, display the ribbon using the `ControlId`:

```
void activeExplorer_SelectionChange()
{
        var ribbon = Globals.Ribbons.YourRibbon;
        if (ribbon.RibbonUI != null)
            ribbon.RibbonUI.ActivateTab("YourRibbonControlId");
}
```

You should set the `ControlId` in the DesignView of your ribbon!